# How to return an item from a list that has no type F#

Tags: f#

I want to return second element of a list. And this input list can be any type. But I don't understand why my code does not work.

```
let test (x: int, y: list<'T>): 'T =
    match y with
    | [] -> 0
    | h :: t -> h
    
test (1, ["a"; "b"; "c"])
test (1, [1; 2; 3])
```

Comment: What would you like the result of your function to be when it's given an empty list as a parameter?

Answer (score 3):

Your code does not *type check* because your implementation restricts the type of the function `test` - it is not `list<'T>` as you specify, but rather just `list<int>`. You can see this in the warning that the compiler gives you on the line where you return `0`:

> warning FS0064: This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 'T has been constrained to be type 'int'.

The issue is that all branches of the `match` construct need to return the same type. If one returns an element of the list and the other `0`, then the compiler infers that the list element must also be of type `int`.

If the function is supposed to work on shorter lists, you could return an option type instead. If it is not, you could throw an exception. A version with exception looks like this:

```
let test (x: int, y: list<'T>): 'T =
  match y with
  | [] -> failwith "Not enough elements"
  | h :: t -> h

test (1, ["a"; "b"; "c"]) // Returns "a"
test (1, [1; 2; 3])       // Returns 1
```

This now runs and returns the first element of the list. Hopefuly, this is enough advice to let you continue figuring things out! To return third element, you'll  need to make the function recursive using `let rec` and make it call itself in the `h :: t` case. I'm not going to show the solution, because I assume you're learning F# and this is a good problem to work on.